# Analyze command for SQLAlchemy alembic

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-migration, alembic

The way I perform migration for a database is 
1. run command `alembic upgrade head` to upgrade the local postgres to match database schema. 
2. update the model to add new column (or index) to a table. 
3. then run `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Message for the migration"` to generate a new migration python file in `migrations/migrate/versions` folder. 
4. then run `almebic upgrade head` again to apply the new change to Postgres. 
5. confirm whether the column (or index) was generated.

Above flow works great for me, but I want to know how much time it took for the migration to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Timing isn't built into Alembic, however you can [time any command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10746) on unix using the time command.

```
time alembic upgrade head
```

See also [Windows equivalent](https://superuser.com/a/228067/220927)